# What is the red animal depicted on this cover of "The Opal Deception"?

Tags: cover-art, artemis-fowl, artemis-fowl-the-opal-deception

My copy of *The Opal Deception* has this cover:

[image: cover, from Amazon]

I can see that the male in the suit and tie is Artemis, and the person next to him is presumably Holly, and the person on the screen is naturally Opal. But what is the red, furry creature with horns on the cover? It doesn't appear to be humanoid, like humans, fairies, or trolls, but I don't know what it might be. What is the red furry creature?

[image]

Comment: It's a troll. :)

Comment: If that's the case, then the artist and I have a *vastly* different idea of what a troll looks like. How is a troll supposed to throw stones and build a bridge with four paws?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a **troll**, as described in the novel. Note the tusks, dreadlocks and glowing eyes, all of which are clearly visible in the picture above.

> *Artemis was beyond amazement at this point, but even so, the sight of
> these magnificent carnivores preying on one another was enough to
> speed his heart up a few beats. He paused to study the nearest
> specimen. It was a terrifying creature: at least eight feet tall, with
> grimy dreadlocks swinging about its massive head. **The troll’s
> fur-matted arms swung below its knees, and two curved serrated tusks
> jutted from its lower jaw. The beast watched them pass, night eyes
> glowing red in their sockets.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Artemis Fowl and the Opal Deception - CHAPTER 7: THE TEMPLE OF ARTEMIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemis_Fowl:_The_Opal_Deception)</sup></sub>